# MySql + InnoDB + PHP Single Quote Discrimination?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

Okay, I've recently converted a number of tables to the InnoDB storage engine and I've been getting errors whenever I use a single-quote ' in the column list of the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO 'Table' ('Col1', 'Col2') VALUES ('Val1', 'Val2')
```

When I tired using phpMyAdmin to generate a proper statement, it looked virtually the same, so I pasted it in my app, and it worked. Then my next statement had the same error so I started to get suspicious. After a bit of playing around I found that the problem was that the query needed a back-tick instead of single-quotes, but not for the whole thing.

```
INSERT INTO `Table` (`Col1`, `Col2`) VALUES ('Val1', 'Val2')
```

works, so it's not like MySql doesn't understand the single-quote. What is going on here? I also can't just leave the columns unquoted like before with MyISAM (ie: Table(Col1, Col2))

Comment: i need to stress the difference between a backtick and single quote more i think :P - think that in some cases backtics are used for system commands. so in php (that u are using) single quotes are for constant text, double quotes allow parsing and backtics are sys commands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because single quotes denote string literals, whereas backticks denote database/table/column identifier escapes.

Removing backticks causes an error because `TABLE` is a reserved word, so in order to use it as a table name you have to include backticks.

Comment: exactly . this example shows why you should allways use them . think for example that some time later they will make your tablename a keyword for some ungodly reason and u r f***ed

Comment: Okay, the table name was just 'table' for the sake of the example, but I see what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You put single quotes around string values, and you use backticks around object names.  The backticks are technically not necessary though unless that name of your table/column is a reserved word or has spaces/funny characters in it.